# Using multiple 'select' HTML element with Vue.js and Materializecss

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, vue.js, vuejs2, materialize

I'm trying to make an HTML multiple select form element with Vue.js. It works perfectly after following [this](https://jsfiddle.net/91bdot7t/31/). However, if I were to add the Materialize css, the select element looks nicer but it does not work and I receive these warnings:

> [Vue warn]: :
>   inline selected attributes on  will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.
>
> [Vue warn]:  expects an Array value for its binding, but got Number 
>   (found in root instance)

This is my Vue.js code:

```
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            selected: 900,
            options: [{
              value: 12,
              text: 12
            }, {
              value: 24,
              text: 24
            }, {
              value: 36,
              text: 36
            }]
          },
```

This is the select element:

```
<select v-model="selected" multiple>
    <option selected value="900">Please Select</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
<label>Select appropraite data type(s)</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining regular **Vue** and regular **Materialize** is not a good idea.
As there  are several conflicting factors which can not easily be resolved, but below are 2 libraries which are helpful. There are few more libraries which are deprecated but the older versions works fine.

[**Vue-Materialize**](https://github.com/paulpflug/vue-materialize) or [**Ceri-Materialize**](https://github.com/ceri-comps/ceri-materialize) will serve your purpose well.